# JsTree Load New Data?

Tags: jquery, jstree

I'm having a hard time removing all the nodes in the tree and then reloading data using the same format that was used in load it using core.data:

```
var root = {};
root.id = "rootid";
root.text = "root";
root.children = [];

$("#tree").jstree({ 
    "core":
    { 
        "data": root,
    }
});
```

I've tried "load_node(root)" but seems to just break the tree.

Answer (score 0):

**JsFiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/r4PSd/

You might define it as JSON, like so:

```
$('#tree').jstree({ 'core' : {
    'data' : [
       { "id" : "ajson1", "parent" : "#", "text" : "Simple root node" },
       { "id" : "ajson2", "parent" : "#", "text" : "Root node 2" },
       { "id" : "ajson3", "parent" : "ajson2", "text" : "Child 1" },
       { "id" : "ajson4", "parent" : "ajson2", "text" : "Child 2" },
    ]
} });
```

via http://www.jstree.com/docs/json/

- or build an array by iteration, like you already do
- it's also possible to do a ajax request to a json source, to load the tree dynamically

Comment: _new_ data, that is initializing the data, after that i need to change it.